# Can I upload a file and assign a category without going to File Manager?

Tags: file-uploads, categories

I'd like to be able to be in an entry text area and make a link to a file I upload. Once uploaded, I see a button to "Edit File" but that only lets you define the meta fields, it doesn't contain the "Categories" tab, like what you'd see if you went to edit the file from File Manager.

Do I need to go to File Manager to specify categories, or is there an easy way to do it from the Upload File/Browse Server dialog that I don't know about?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I normally create a Channel to hold a file repository. This way I can assign other custom fields to the file and categories in one shot. For example, an Mp3 + transcript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any options for deciding the categories for the files through that initial Upload File/Browse Server dialog. The File Manager is definitely your best bet! If it's really important to you, I'd put in a Feature Request!